# Is this an effective workout?

Tags: exercise, gym

Now, I know that this video is for pure comedy, but the man in the white shirt doing an effective workout at all?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGR960H1Jmw

If not, then why so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those were parodies of real exercises.

If those exercises were done with perfect form *(and seriousness)*, they are very effective.

They are examples of **body weight exercises** and they are very good for the body.

Comment: Did you find this video funny?

Comment: Nope; I found it pathetic *(or sad)*.